# About missing DLL when loading solution from TFS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, tfs

I'm not so sure if the checker (who checks in) and the loader do something wrong or TFS has some feature I don't know of which helps the checker check in just what the TFS suggests (listed as ***Included files***) but still helps the loader load the solution easily without having to do any other step (such as fix missing-DLL problem, reinstall missing DLL using nuget, ...).

Currently if the checker checks in all referenced DLLs, the problem would not occur. However that's not what TFS suggests you by default. So that's the hardest thing to understand (to me). Without checking-in DLL (by using ***Add items to folder*** first), the loader after loading the solution will have the DLLs missed out. What I want is when the loader loads any solution from TFS, he does not need to do any further step (very bothering and even sometimes impossible to solve easily) before just building and running the solution. Of course if the current local folder has all necessary DLLs, you won't see the problem. The problem occurs just the first time you load the solution or at sometime you switch to a new one (using Get a specific version) and overwrite the local completely.

I'm fairly new to TFS. If I was the only one playing both role of checker and loader, I would choose to check-in the DLLs but I'm not sure if that's the right way.

Answer (score 3):

This is not TFS-specific at all. It occurs with all kinds of version control, and in all environments where people are not careful with what kind of horrible project and solution files they check in.

Rule one: do **not** check in output assemblies. Rule two: do not reference projects outside your solution root. Rule three: do **not, ever** reference output assemblies (`bin\Debug\Foo.dll`). Make a project reference or create a NuGet package. Rule four: use NuGet for package management, and use a private NuGet server as primary or fallback so that you can build when (your connection to) the Internet or NuGet are down. Rule five: if, **if** you must link a project from different solutions, only update its packages from its "home" solution, otherwise the packages path will be messed up.

Those simple rules will make sure that your projects and solutions can be shared amongst colleagues. But you'd be surprised at how many people do this wrong, and refuse to alter their way of working with references, actively causing harm to their colleague's productivity.

A very simple check is to do a clean Get of your solution and try to compile it. If you get reference warnings (which cascade to compiler errors), you've done something wrong. Open your .csproj files in a text editor. If anywhere there's more than one `..\`, you're in trouble.

Comment: The first 3 rules are understandable (and in fact that's what I've followed for a long time). However it's unclear about using Nuget Package. Do you mean when using Nuget Package, the dlls should be referenced (even with no loading time) automatically after loading the solution from TFS? I'm not so sure but our solution does use Nuget Package (when opening the manager, it shows a list of installed packages) but strangely the references (under Reference node) are marked with yellow warning sign (indicating of missing dll). I have to use `update-package` command, that's still bothering...

Comment: I find in the project's text content this ***<HintPath>..\..\\*** (inside <Reference> node) (and there are many more references). So that means it's really wrong? Do you know what could lead to that and how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Well yeah then that's the problem. Packages are stored solution-relative, so someone is updating packages from another solution.

Comment: You can fix it by editing the .csproj file and making all NuGet references start with "..\packages".